# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to `React Native` and am getting this error:

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped

Code:

```
render(){
    return(
      <UpperPadding>
        <View style={styles.upperContainer}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Actions.register()>
            <Image
            source={require('./../images/registerbutton.png')} style={styles.background}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight> //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
        </View>
      </UpperPadding>
    );
  }
}
```

Thankful for any help!
Thanks!

Comment: `onPress={() => Actions.register()}>`

Comment: you forgot to close the `{`, write it like this: `onPress={() => Actions.register()}>`

Comment: Oh wow, thanks alot! <3